# Cortana Skill works on Windows 10, but not on iOS

Tags: azure-bot-service, cortana, cortana-invoke

I created a chatbot using Azure Bot Services and published it to the Cortana channel. It works on my Windows 10 PC, but not on my iPhone using the Cortana app 3.0.0.13220. I use exactly the same user account and invocation phrase.

Are custom skills supported for the iOS app?